# Send request to google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

when I get the coordinates, I need send request like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55.75320193022759,37.61922086773683&sensor=false&language=ru
```

, but how i can send this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Google Maps API v3 use the geocoding service

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.75320193022759, 37.61922086773683);

geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert(results[1].formatted_address);
    } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
    }
});
```

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding